# How do I extract with sed numeric characters between two characters?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, text-formatting

I have a random text, followed by a colon (`:`) and a space,
then a numeric result, then another space and other arbitrary text;
for example:

```
text: 30 (5 new)
```

I need to extract only the number `30`; for example:

```
30
```

Currently I only have this code:

```
sed 's/.*: //g'
```

which only gives me this result:

```
30 (5 new)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression (`'s/.*: //g'`) deletes the first part, but keeps all the rest. This one replaces the entire line with the part which has only the desired numbers:

`sed -re 's/^.*: ([0-9]+) .*$/\1/'`

Details: `^.*:` is the first part (fit to the begining of the line), your number is the next `([0-9]+)`, it's in brackets to define a group what you can use later, and finally the rest of the line till the end: `.*$`.
And you replace that to the first group (we have only one): `\1`

Comment: When the search string for a substitute command is anchored at the beginning (``^``) *or* the end (``$``) — and, of course, yours is both — then the substitution can occur only once, and so there’s no benefit to appending the `g` (global) option.

Comment: thank you so much redseven ! this works for me !

Comment: Thanks G-Man, I've edited it. (Why not to create an edit request?)

Comment: I didn’t edit your answer because it wasn’t wrong; it just had an unnecessary letter in it.  And, while I do sometimes edit posts to make minor changes, I just didn’t feel like it in this case. If I *only* edited your answer, you might not understand why (and some people have even reverted improvements I’ve made).  Editing and explaining would have been more work (although, of course, I’m exceeding that threshold now).  By only commenting, I (potentially) educated you and anybody else who saw the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
$ echo "text: 30 (5 new)" | sed -e 's/^.*: \([0-9][0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
30
```

To break that down:

- The `^.*:` matches, from the beginning of a line, any number of characters that end with a colon and a space
- The `\([0-9][0-9]*\)` matches a number.  The parentheses define a group that we can refer to later.
- The `.*$` matches any number of characters up the end of the line

We substitute (`s`) that entire pattern with `\1`, which is the content of the first group (i.e., the group we defined with the parentheses -- the number).

Comment: thank you Andy! also great solution and answering other issues i had as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are imprecise about what might come after the number. 
   If there might be another colon, e.g.,

   ```
   eggs: 42 (from: 17 hens)
   ```

   then the other answers will give you `17`. 
   If that’s what you want, fine
   (but please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/527048/edit) your question to say what you want). 
   If you want the number after the *first* colon,
   use `^[^:]*` instead of `^.*`.
2. You are imprecise about what a “numeric result” is. 
   If you might have:

   ```
   balance: 609.83 (I’m running low on money)
   balance: -17.42 (overdraft!)
   ```

   - First of all,
     please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/527048/edit) your question to say what your numbers look like.
   - Your question title says “between two characters”. 
     If you guarantee that the numeric result (whatever it may be)
     is followed by a space (and does not *contain* any space(s)!), then

     ```
     sed 's/^[^:]*: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
     ```

     might be the most direct solution. 
     This will capture any non-blank characters that follow the `:` . 
     Note that this will handle cases where the number is at the end of the line
     (not followed by a space):

     ```
     Blind mice: 3
     ```

   (Note that [Andy Dalton’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/527048/edit)
   will also handle cases where the number is at the end of the line.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below 2 methods

First method using awk

```
awk '{print $2}' filename
```